# How can I store different inputs in a single variable and print them out?

Tags: python-3.x

So far the code works and asks for everything I need it to, but it keeps shooting out the last input instead of all 3 at the end. I know why but don't know how to fix. Any help appreciated.

I've tried doing 3 separate functions but just made it messy, and couldn't get it to work.

```
class RetailItem:

    def __items__(s,d,p):
            return s,d,p
    def main():
        for x in range (3):
            s = input("What is item name: ")
            d = int(input("How many of these items are in stock? "))
            p = float(input("How much is each unit price? "))
        for __items__ in range(3):
            print("Description:", s)
            print("Units:", d)
            print("Price:", p)
    main()
```

so right now the code does this.

```
What is item name: 1
How many of these items are in stock? 1
How much is each unit price? 1
What is item name: 2
How many of these items are in stock? 2
How much is each unit price? 2
What is item name: 3
How many of these items are in stock? 3
How much is each unit price? 3
Description: 3
Units 3
Price 3.0
Description: 3
Units 3
Price 3.0
Description: 3
Units 3
Price 3.0
```

at the end I want it to read.

```
Description: 1
Units 1
Price 1
Description: 2
Units 2
Price 2
Description: 3
Units 3
Price 3
```

Comment: In the loop, every item you enter (except the last) is replaced because you store to same variable each time. And this looks strange: `for __items__ in range(3):`

Answer (score 0):

In each iteration of your loop you are overriding the previous value your variables hold.

This may be over complicated for your goal but you could nest dictionaries inside a list as a data structure.

**example:**

```
#initialize an empty list and dict
myList = []
myDict = {}
def main():
    for x in range (3):
        #each loop overrides the dict
        myDict["description"] = input("What is item name: ")
        myDict["units"] = int(input("How many of these items are in stock? "))
        myDict["price"] = float(input("How much is each unit price? "))
        #append a copy of dict to our list
        myList.append(myDict.copy())
    #loop through list and unpack values from dictionaries
    for item in myList:
        for key, value in item.items():
            print(key.capitalize() + ":" + str(value))

main()
```

**input:**

```
What is item name: 1
How many of these items are in stock? 1
How much is each unit price? 1
What is item name: 2
How many of these items are in stock? 2
How much is each unit price? 2
What is item name: 3
How many of these items are in stock? 3
How much is each unit price? 3
```

**output:**

```
Description:1
Units:1
Price:1.0
Description:2
Units:2
Price:2.0
Description:3
Units:3
Price:3.0
```

There may be an easier way to accomplish what you are trying to do but this way you can keep track of inputs, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
s,d,p = [],[],[]
for x in range(3):
        s.append(input("What is item name: "))
        d.append(int(input("How many of these items are in stock? ")))
        p.append(float(input("How much is each unit price? ")))
for i in range(3):
        print("Description:", s[i])
        print("Units:", d[i])
        print("Price:", p[i])
```

Other possibility is to create an array:

```py
array = [[],[],[]]
for x in range(3):
        array[0].append(input("What is item name: "))
        array[1].append(int(input("How many of these items are in stock? ")))
        array[2].append(float(input("How much is each unit price? ")))
for i in range(3):
        print("Description:", array[0][i])
        print("Units:", array[1][i])
        print("Price:", array[2][i])
```